# Booger like things growing on my walls

Tags: mycology

Can someone help me dealing with this? They're constantly growing on my walls whether I clean them or not. They're very solid.[image]

[image]

I live in Yerevan, Armenia. The place where these creatures are, is my apartment which was renovated before I moved here. They've been more than just these two, I removed them but they're still growing. The size is similar to booger size, some of them might be bigger, so 3cm+ and as for the photos, it's required to post no more than 2mb and I don't know how to post a better quality as I only have a phone.

Comment: Magnifying glass? Also, please [edit] your post to include your additional info. Thanks

Comment: @theforestecologist I don't have a magnifying glass. Do you have an email that I can send photos? I'm trying to take better quality photos with more than 2 megabytes that are not allowed here.

Comment: No email. You could try cropping them to reduce size.

Comment: Do you think these could be mold?

Comment: if you crop the pictures before uploading them they will fit,what type of material is in the walls,concrete,wood,stone?

Comment: @trondhansen it's mostly concrete covered with wallpapers. They're mostly growing on wallpapers and rarely on fabrics, however one time I saw it on my tv screen. I stripped that off from the tv screen and after 1-2 days I saw it's grown again the same place on screen. I removed that and cleaned the screen with alcohol and it never grew again.